# angular 5 lazy loading vs dynamic loading

Tags: angular-cli, angular5, angular-components

Can somebody explain the difference between lazy loading modules and dynamic component loading in angular 5? I have some hard time to figure out when what to use. Can you provide a use case for each so I can better understand them? I am pretty new to angular 5... I know that lazy loading is about modules and dynamic components loading is about components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With lazy loaded modules the browser will only load features when the user navigates to their routes for the first time. When you add components directly to your routes they will be loaded regardless if you are in any particular route, so in terms of performance and initial bundle size it is always good to have features lazy loaded.

Reference: https://alligator.io/angular/lazy-loading/

Answer (score 0):

- Lazy loading modules speeds up our applications startup time with features to ease load times and increase performance.
- Lazy loading creates multiple bundles and loads them on demand in runtime in the browser whenever requested.
- If we had loaded all our components and templates into one big bundle, it would lead to a large performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

`'dynamic loading'` and `'lazy loading'` are different terms for the behavior.  Both are conditionally loaded on the website - For ex. when user clicks a `modal-button`, we want to load the code for the `modal` - this is *dynamic-behavior*.  It can also be said that the `modal` was *lazily-loaded* when the user clicked the button.

Good Luck...